# create a new object of group of field in select query in objection js

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, orm, objection.js

I have one select query in Objections JS(NodeJs). That will return few fields. I need to modify the result. Suppose we have got below json from the response of the query.

```
{
   group_id, 
   group_name,
   link,
   created,
   user_id
}
```

I need to update this response like below with the use of the loop of the.

```
{
   group: {
      id, 
      name,
   },
   link,
   created,
   user_id
}
```

Is there any option in objections to updating our result like this? Please help me with this concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this for getting the response as you mentioned above.

```
SELECT 
   JSON_OBJECT('id', group_id, 'name', group_name) as group, 
   link,
   created,
   user_id FROM table_name;
```

Comment: I have an older version of MySQL so the JSON_OBJECT function is not working for me.